# Laravel 5.4 y Socialite

Tags: laravel-5, laravel

Estaba funcionando correctamente y de la noche a la mañana ya no me dejaba realizar el *login* por medio de **Facebook** me aparece el siguiente error:

> {"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query
>   information about the current user.","type":"OAuthExce (truncated...)

Answer (score 0):

Solo es necesario actualizar el paquete de Laravel Socialite.

```
composer update
```